# error stopped application when press back key and rotate

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, media-player

> I added new interface as i can call android methods in **html** . Main activity call **html** files to my **webview** and interface class to execute play method for play sound . all thing worked well but when i added my code to stop sound when close the app or turn off the sound when press back key or home key . but error " **application stopped ...**" happened when press back or home key also when rotate .

```
public class x extends Activity {

private MediaPlayer mp;
private String TAG;
Context mContext;
private IntentListener listener = new IntentListener();
WebAppInterface wb= new WebAppInterface(mContext);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);


    //Call HTML Files
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_engine);

    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");

    // Intiate interface

    myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");


}
@Override
 protected void onPause()
 {
     super.onPause();
     if(mp.isPlaying())
     mp.pause(); //stop the sound
 }

 @Override
 protected void onResume() 
 {
     super.onResume();
     if(WebAppInterface.checked)
     {
         mp.start();
     }
 }
 @Override
 protected void onDestroy() 
 {
     super.onDestroy();
     if(WebAppInterface.checked)
     {
         mp.stop();
     }
 }
```

}

```
public class WebAppInterface    {
Context mContext;
 private MediaPlayer mp;
 public static boolean checked = false;
/** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
WebAppInterface(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}


@JavascriptInterface
public void playsound(String value  ) {
    if (value.equals("on")) {
        checked = true;
        mp= MediaPlayer.create(mContext,R.raw.sound);
        mp.setLooping(true);
        mp.start();
    }
    else 
    {  
        checked = false;
        mp.stop();
    }
}
```

}

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.ramadan.Ramadan"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
```

```
07-01 01:06:29.628: E/AndroidRuntime(631): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.ramadan/com.ramadan.Ramadan}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to initialize media player from interface class in Android Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17400864/how-to-initialize-media-player-from-interface-class-in-android-java)

Answer (score 1):

edit version 2:
From your comment

```
mp is media player and it is initialized in interface , so can i initialize it on activity but from the interface
```

The way your code is structure is not correct then. You have two variable called mp. So lets rename the variable to be more clear.

```
private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayerActivity;  
private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayerWebApp;
```

In your interface you initialize mMediaPlayerWebApp here.

```
public void playsound(String value  ) {
    if (value.equals("on")) {
        checked = true;
        mMediaPlayerWebApp= MediaPlayer.create(mContext,R.raw.sound);
        mMediaPlayerWebApp.setLooping(true);
        mMediaPlayerWebApp.start();
    }
    else 
    {  
        checked = false;
        mMediaPlayerWebApp.stop();
    }
}
```

In your activity you do not initialize mMediaPlayerActivity at all. But you try to use it on your onDestory/onPause event. For your code to work you need to remove mMediaPlayerActivity all together and use your mMediaPlayerWebApp. How would you do that in activity? Here

```
@Override
 protected void onDestroy() 
 {
     super.onDestroy();
     if(WebAppInterface.checked)
     {
         WebAppInterface.mMediaPlayerWebApp.stop(); //change mMediaPlayer to public
     }
 }
```

Now that's out a way, I can see another potential problem in your code. What if playSound() is never called? When you try to call mMediaPlayerWebApp.stop() you'll get another nullpointerexception because it never got a chance to go! Another issue in your code is that it lacks [Encapsulation](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_encapsulation.htm) , fundamental OOP concepts.

So here how I would rewrite you code.

```
public class WebAppInterface 
{
    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayerWebApp;
    private boolean mHasSoundPlaying = false;

    WebAppInterface(Context context) 
    {
        mMediaPlayerWebApp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound);
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void playsound(String value) 
    {
        if (value.equals("on")) 
        {
            setSoundPlaying(true);
        } else 
        {
            setSoundPlaying(false);
        }
    }

    public void setSoundPlaying(Boolean isPlaying) 
    {
        this.mHasSoundPlaying = isPlaying;

        if (isPlaying) 
        {
            mMediaPlayerWebApp.setLooping(true);
            mMediaPlayerWebApp.start();
        }
        else
        {
            if (mMediaPlayerWebApp.isPlaying())
            {
                mMediaPlayerWebApp.stop();  
            }
        }
    }

public void pauseSound()
{
    this.mMediaPlayerWebApp.pause();
}


public Boolean getSoundPlaying()
{
    return this.mHasSoundPlaying;
}
}
```

Then in your activity just use the setSoundPlaying(boolean) method to 
make it stop or start.

Now I notice a third potential bug. In your activity.

```
WebAppInterface wb= new WebAppInterface(mContext);
```

mContext is not initialize either. Just change this to

```
WebAppInterface wb;
```

And then in the OnCreate()

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);


    //Call HTML Files
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_engine);

    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");

    // Instantiate interface

    this.wb = new WebAppInterface(this);

    myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(this.wb, "Android");
}
```

Overall I would recommend and pickup a pure java book. You need to familiarize with some basic OOP concepts. These concepts help your code from falling into NullPointerException as well makes it easier to track down bugs.

---

Original message to this question: 
Another thing I notice is that in your Activty you have something called

```
private MediaPlayer mp;
```

and then farther down you have this

```
 @Override
 protected void onDestroy() 
 {
     super.onDestroy();
     if(WebAppInterface.checked)
     {
         mp.stop();
     }
 }
```

I don't see anywhere MediaPlayer mp is initialize anywhere in your activity. Until it's initialize you can't call any methods on it or else it'll cause nullpointerexception.

Comment: mp is media player and it is initialized in interface , so can i initialize it on activity but from the interface

Answer (score 0):

`MediaPlayer mp` is not initialized. So, you get NPE.