# How to initialize media player from interface class in Android Java?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, android-mediaplayer

I know that i have to call `onpause()` or `ondestroy()` methods to stop media player I must initialize the media player but in my case, I call html and use interface between android and html as call android methods on html. I try to have instance from interface as:

```
WebAppInterface wb= new WebAppInterface(mContext);
```

and at the interface I initialized the media player:

```
public  MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(mContext,R.raw.sound);
```

and in main activity I try to initalize the media player in the  `oncreate()` method:

```
    mediaplayer=wb.mp;
```

MainActivity:

```
public class Ramadan extends Activity {

private MediaPlayer mediaplayer;

Context mContext;

WebAppInterface wb= new WebAppInterface(mContext);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);


    //Call HTML Files
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_engine);

    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");

    // Intiate interface

    myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
    mediaplayer=wb.mp;


}
@Override
 protected void onPause()
 {
     super.onPause();
     if(mediaplayer.isPlaying())
     mediaplayer.pause(); //stop the sound
 }

 @Override
 protected void onResume() 
 {
     super.onResume();
     if(WebAppInterface.checked)
     {
         mediaplayer.start();
     }
 }
 @Override
 protected void onDestroy() 
 {
     super.onDestroy();
     if(WebAppInterface.checked)
     {
         mediaplayer.stop();
     }
 }
```

Interface:

```
Context mContext;
public  MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(mContext,R.raw.sound);
 public static boolean checked = false;
/** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
WebAppInterface(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}


/** Show a toast from the web page */
@JavascriptInterface
public void playsound(String value  ) {
    if (value.equals("on")) {
        checked = true;

        mp.setLooping(true);
        mp.start();
    }
    else 
    {  
        checked = false;
        mp.stop();
    }
}
}
```

Logcat:

```
07-01 10:56:20.421: E/AndroidRuntime(636): java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.ramadan/com.ramadan.Ramadan}:     java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems your mediaplayer is not yet initialized when onResume is called. More about [MediaPlayer State Diagram](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)

[EDIT-1

And try `mp` initialization inside constructor i.e:

```
public  MediaPlayer mp = null;
public static boolean checked = false;
/** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
WebAppInterface(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
    //Initialize mp here.
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(mContext,R.raw.sound);
}
```

EDIT-1]

[EDIT-2

Initialise `WebAppInterface` once and pass that reference to `addJavascriptInterface()`. i.e :

```
WebAppInterface wb=null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);


    //Call HTML Files
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_engine);

    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");

    //Initialise WebAppInterface and pass this ref..
    wb=new WebAppInterface(this);
    myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(wb, "Android");
    mediaplayer=wb.mp;
}
```

EDIT-2]

Comment: but i initialized it on oncreate() as i added  mediaplayer=wb.mp; so why it isnot initialized

Comment: the application stopped when it started

Comment: Please post stack trace of crash

Comment: 07-01 14:12:24.918: E/AndroidRuntime(634): java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.ramadan/com.ramadan.Ramadan}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Please check EDIT-2 which is actual fix I suppose.

Comment: you are very genius i was more than 5 days on this issue thanks more chandan